# I'm trying to change the color of an imageview with a boolean, what am I missing?

Tags: java, android, imageview, boolean

I have a button that encompasses the entire screen of my phone and I have two spots on that button that when pressed will switch between true and false of my boolean and that function is suppose to switch the color of an imageview that sits in the middle of my screen

if the boolean is true the middle image is suppose to be red
if the boolean is false the middle image is suppose to turn green

I thought I understood how to work a boolean but obviously not considering I'm unable to switch the color freely back and forth like I want to

I want the middle imageview to be red when the app starts and if I hit the right spot it'll turn from red to green, and if it's green and I hit the other specific spot it turns back to red, and so on

If anyone has any advice on how I can make this happen I would appreciate it Thankyou

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Display mainDisplay;
ViewGroup mainLayout;
ImageButton touchpad;
Context ourContext;
ImageView mainblock;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutPositioner;

boolean redBlock;

float offsetX = 0;
float offsetY = 0;

float padPOS_x = 0;
float padPOS_y = 0;

float designSize_w = 540;
float designSize_h = 960;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//Remove title bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);//Hides notification bar
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    mainDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    mainLayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.id_layout);   
    mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xFF667C26);

    DisplayMetrics m = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(m);
    int windowHeight = m.heightPixels;
    int windowWidth = m.widthPixels;
    int h = windowHeight; 
    int w = windowWidth;
    offsetX = (w / 540.0f);
    offsetY = (h / 960.0f);

    ourContext = this;

    ImageView leftbox = new ImageView(ourContext);
    SetPos(75, 100, 100, 100);
    leftbox.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    leftbox.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000A0);
    mainLayout.addView(leftbox);

    ImageView rightbox = new ImageView(ourContext);
    rightbox.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000A0);
    SetPos(350, 100, 100, 100);
    rightbox.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    mainLayout.addView(rightbox);

    mainblock = new ImageView(this);
    SetPos(100, 500, 300, 300);
    mainblock.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    mainLayout.addView(mainblock);
    redBlock = true;

    touchpad = new ImageButton(this);
    SetPos(padPOS_x,padPOS_y,designSize_w,designSize_h);
    touchpad.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    touchpad.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
    mainLayout.addView(touchpad);
    touchpad.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //when touch pad is touched

        if (
                (!redBlock) &&
                (event.getX() > 75) && (event.getX() < 175) &&
                (event.getY() > 100) && (event.getY() < 200)
            )
                    //if I touch left block and mainblock is green ...
            {
            redBlock = true;

            //main black becomes red
            }

        if (
                (redBlock) &&
                (event.getX() > 350) && (event.getX() < 450) &&
                (event.getY() > 100) && (event.getY() < 200)
            )
                    //if I touch right block and mainblock is red ...
            {
            redBlock = false;

            //main black becomes red
            }

        return false;
    }
});

    if(redBlock)
    {
    mainblock.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE42217); //lavared

    }

else if(!redBlock)
    {
    mainblock.setBackgroundColor(0xFF57E964); //stoplightgreen

    }
}


public void SetPos(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
    layoutPositioner = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutPositioner.topMargin = (int) (offsetY * y);
    layoutPositioner.leftMargin = (int) (offsetX * x);
    layoutPositioner.width = (int)(width * offsetX);
    layoutPositioner.height = (int)(height * offsetY);      
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: If the code to switch colors is in `onCreate`, then won't it only execute upon creation? Don't you have to put that code inside your `onTouch` listener so it can execute when you touch it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have some tips that may help you.

1. Your way to change background color is your onCreate method. That means that it will be executed only in the moment that your Activity is being created. And, because of that, your boolean actually can change but that's it.. you're not doing any work with the backgroundColor. You need to call a method that changes the color in the touch event.
2. Every subclass of View object in Android (that includes ImageView, Button and so..) has a capability of having an TouchListener/ClickListener. Working with that can help you narrow down your effort of handle what is being clicked. With that, you no longer will need to check XY coordinates if it's in view bounds..

Comment: Holy Krap ... I knew the fix was going to be something simple I missed thanks Lucas & Shashank ... works like a charm now :)